# How can I print an Outlook email?

Tags: python, outlook, com-automation

After I open an outlook email, I need to print the body. Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client as client

outlook=client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
print(inbox.Items.Count)
print(inbox.Parent.Name)
for i in range(5):
    message = messages.GetNext()
    print(""+message.Subject, str(message.ReceivedTime))
    print(message.Body)
```

And the error is this:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:/Users/source/repos/Tests/pru.py", line 12, in <module>
>     print(message.Body)
>   File "C:\Users\venvs\frameworkenv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 583, in __getattr__
>     return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
>   File "C:\Users\venvs\frameworkenv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 572, in _ApplyTypes_
>     self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
> ```

Comment: Try to use the `HTMLBody` property instead of `Body`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is related to accessing Outlook item's properties. The following code assumes you deal with `MailItem` objects by default:

```
print(""+message.Subject, str(message.ReceivedTime))
print(message.Body)
```

But the fact is that a folder may contain different item types such as appointments, notes, tasks, documents and etc. So, before accessing `MailItem` specific properties I'd suggest checking the item's type. For example, you may try to use the following code:

```
# Find only mail items and report, note, meeting etc items
if '_MailItem' in str(type(message)):
   print(type(message))
```

Also that could occur if you tried to read the `Body` property of an SMIME message using code. Was that email signed/encrypted?

See [Reading MailItem.Body throws COMException "An error occurred in the underlying security system"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a02a1bde-40ed-45e2-abe6-bc7e54923352/reading-mailitembody-throws-comexception-an-error-occurred-in-the-underlying-security-system?forum=outlookdev) for more information on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your code prints me the following: <class 'win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6._MailItem'> but I dont if I should convert the type or how to proceed.

Comment: The string indicates the message class of Outlook items. Is this printed for all items in the loop?

Comment: Yes it is printed for all items

Comment: Was the email signed/encrypted?

Comment: It is for my company account, I also tried sending an email from my gmail account but with no success.